# $V$ is a unitary space , $T : V \to V$ , linear operator. Exist $TT^{*}=6T-8I$. Prove $T$ is positive operator.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

$V$ is a unitary space , $T : V \to V$ , linear operator.

Exist $TT^{*}=6T-8I$.

Prove $T$ is positive operator.

$\exists v \in V, \lambda \in \mathbb C$ such that $T(v)=\lambda v \implies T^*(v)=\overline{\lambda} v.$

$TT^{*}=6T-8I \implies TT^{*}-6T+8I=0.$

$TT^{*}(v)-6T(v)+8v=T(\overline{\lambda} v)-6\lambda v+8=\overline{\lambda}T( v)-6\lambda v+8$

$=\overline{\lambda} \lambda v -6\lambda v+8 \implies \lambda^2-6\lambda+8=0 \implies \lambda_1=4,\lambda_2=2.$

$\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are positive then $T$ is positive operator.

Is my proof correct ?

I'd be grateful for your feedback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your proof is at best incomplete. In particular, it is not clear what you are trying to say with "$\exists v \in V, \lambda \in \mathbb C$ such that $T(v)=\lambda v \implies T^*(v)=\overline{\lambda} v.$" Is this a statement that is supposed to be true for all operators $T:V \to V$? If so, then your assumption about this statement is incorrect. Is this the statement that you are trying to show holds for $T$? If so, then I don't see how you have done this through your proof.

Also, you replace $\bar \lambda \lambda$ with $\lambda^2$, which is incorrect.

To fix your proof, I would break the proof into the following two steps.

1. Show that $T = T^*$
2. Using this, show (as you have in your proof) that the eigenvalues of $T$ must be equal to $2$ or $4$.

---

As an alternative approach, it suffices to show directly that for any non-zero $v \in V$, we have $\langle Tv, v \rangle > 0$. To that end, note that
$$
TT^* = 6T - 8I \implies T = \frac 16 TT^* + \frac 43 I,
$$
so that if $v \in V$ with $v \neq 0$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\langle Tv, v\rangle &= 
\left \langle
\left(\frac 16 TT^* + \frac 43 I \right)v,v
\right\rangle
\\ & = 
\frac 16 \langle TT^* v, v\rangle + \frac 43 \langle v,v \rangle
\\ & = \frac 16 \langle T^*v, T^*v \rangle + \frac 43 \langle v,v \rangle > 0.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: $(6T)^*=(TT^{*}+8I)^*=(TT^{*})^*+8I^*=TT^{*}+8I=6T  \implies T=T^*$

Comment: @erez Yes, that's how I would show that $T = T^*$.